# Проблема Python

Tags: python

Скачал пайтон 3.7.3, запускаю ком. строку и ввожу python -v . Всё как нужно но в ком. строке появляется очень много текста[image: это не весь текст, но он есть] у меня 7 винда 32 бит, не знаю что делать...

Comment: а зачем вы добавляете `-v`?

Comment: @ExplodingKitten Команда -V версию Python'a

Answer (score 0):

Если вашей целью было узнать версию установленного Python'a, то вы ввели не верный агрумент. Аргумент `-v` импортирует все модули Python'a. Вам нужен агрумент `-V` (с заглавной буквы), именно он покажет текущую версию Python'a.
Использование: `python -V`

И вот вам совет: чтобы избежать подобных вопросов на форумах, вводите аргумент `--help или -h`, чтобы получить информацию обо всех доступных аргументах и их функциях